# How to find those 64 SURF descriptors to feed them to a Neural Network in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Im trying to find out SURF descriptors from a foreground mask, well i got them but im a novice at this, what i want are those 64 or 128 SURF descriptors which I will give as input to a Neural Network, what i cant find is where are those 64 descriptors??

the code is as follows:

```
I = imread('Sample.jpg');

points = detectHarrisFeatures(I);  % for corners
Temp = SURFPoints(points.Location); % converts coners to SURF points

[features, validPtsObj] = extractFeatures(I, Temp,'SURFSize',64);
```

when i chceck in command prompt i get lengths as

```
length(points) = 187
length(features) = 187
length(validPtsObj) = 187
```

where are those 64 or 128 descriptors ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what it looks like to me is happening is that you are extracting some corners via the harris corner detector - it finds 187 corners. At these points you then calculate the surf features (at this line : `Temp = SURFPoints(points.Location)`) and convert them into the vectors you are expecting (at this line: `[features, validPtsObj] = extractFeatures(I, Temp,'SURFSize',64);` ) 
My guess is that the values you are looking for are stored in the struct which you called "features". So the surf feature - a vector of size 64) for each corner would be stored in `features{1} .... features{187}`. (You can check this by doing `length(features{1})`.)

Just a point though, usually neural networks you would want to feed in raw pixel values and let the network find the relations between raw data instead of hand made features. If you want to go with SURF features I suggest you try feeding this into an SVM instead.